# Use MinMaxScaler on training data to generate std, min and max to be used on testing data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, minmax

How would I use the scikit-learn `MinMaxScaler` to standardize every column in a pandas data-frame training data set, but use the exact same standard deviation, min/max formula on my test data set?

Since my testing data is unknown to the model, I dont want to standardize the whole data set, it would not be an accurate model for future unknown data. Instead I would like to standardize the data between 0 & 1 using the training set, and use the same std, min and max numbers for the formula on the test data.

(Obviously I can write my own min-max scaler, but wondering if scikit-learn can do this already or if there is a library I can use for this first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `fit` it on your training data and then `transform` your test data:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)  # or: fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Your approach now seems like good practice.  If you were to call `fit` on your entire X matrix (train and test combined), you'd be causing information leakage as your training data would have "seen" the scale of your test data beforehand.  Using a class-based implementation of `MinMaxScaler()` is how sklearn addresses this specifically, allowing the object to "remember" attributes of the data on which it was fit.

However, be aware that `MinMaxScaler()` does *not* scale to ~N(0, 1).  In fact, it is explicitly billed as an alternative to this scaling.  In other words, it does not guarantee you unit variance or 0 mean at all.  In fact, it really doesn't care about standard deviation as it's defined in the traditional sense.

From the docstring:

> The transformation is given by:
>
> ```
> X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
> X_scaled = X_std * (max_ - min_) + min_
> ```

Where `min_` and `max_` are equal to your unpacked `feature_range` (default `(0, 1)`) from the `__init__` of `MinMaxScaler()`.  Manually this is:

```
def scale(a):
    # implicit feature_range=(0,1)
    return (a - X_train.min(axis=0)) / (X_train.max(axis=0) - X_train.min(axis=0))
```

So say you had:
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
np.random.seed(444)

X = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=(200, 3))
y = np.random.normal(loc=-5, scale=3, size=X.shape[0])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, random_state=444)
```

If you were to call

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Know that [`scaler.scale_`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L349) is *not* standard deviation of the data on which you did the fitting.

```
scaler.scale_
# array([ 0.0843,  0.0852,  0.0876])

X_train.std(axis=0)
# array([ 2.042 ,  2.0767,  2.1285])
```

Instead, it is:

```
(1 - 0) / (X_train.max(axis=0) - X_train.min(axis=0))
# array([ 0.0843,  0.0852,  0.0876])
```

Comment: @Terry For std, you may need StandardScaler.